# Mongoose Error must pass in valid bson parser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have a docker container (running a testing suite environment) that has stopped work on me. I'm using Mongoose 4.13.17. The problem I'm running into is every time I try to run my test cases it tries to connect to a testing db container but I get this error message.

```
Error: must pass in valid bson parser
at new Pool (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:105:13)
at Server.connect (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:373:17)
at Server.connect (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:368:17)
at open (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:229:19)
at Db.open (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:252:44)
at createServer (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:391:6)
at /srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:512:14
at parseHandler (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:117:38)
at module.exports (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:97:5)
at connect (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:485:3)
at Function.MongoClient.connect (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:250:3)
at /srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:820:25
at Promise._execute (/srv/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:313:9)
at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/srv/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
at new Promise (/srv/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:819:17)
at Mongoose.connect (/srv/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:262:17)
at new App (/srv/app/src/app.ts:34:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/app/src/app.ts:80:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Module.replacementCompile (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:58:13)
at Module.m._compile (/srv/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
at module.exports (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/default-require-extensions/js.js:7:9)
at /srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:62:4
at require.extensions.(anonymous function) (/srv/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:62:4)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/app/src/server.ts:6:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Module.replacementCompile (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:58:13)
at Module.m._compile (/srv/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
at module.exports (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/default-require-extensions/js.js:7:9)
at /srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:62:4
at require.extensions.(anonymous function) (/srv/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:62:4)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/app/test/unit/rest/Audio.test.ts:3:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Module.replacementCompile (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:58:13)
at Module.m._compile (/srv/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
at module.exports (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/default-require-extensions/js.js:7:9)
at /srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:62:4
at require.extensions.(anonymous function) (/srv/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:62:4)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at /srv/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:250:27
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Mocha.loadFiles (/srv/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:247:14)
at Mocha.run (/srv/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:576:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/app/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:637:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Module.replacementCompile (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:58:13)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/node_modules/append-transform/index.js:62:4)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at runMain (/root/.node-spawn-wrap-45-4803909aaae7/node:68:10)
at Function.<anonymous> (/root/.node-spawn-wrap-45-4803909aaae7/node:171:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/app/node_modules/nyc/bin/wrap.js:23:4)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at /root/.node-spawn-wrap-45-4803909aaae7/node:178:8
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.node-spawn-wrap-45-4803909aaae7/node:181:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:279:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:696:3)
```

I've looked all around for a solution but it doesn't seem like this is an extremely common problem. 
This is what my class looks like:

```
import * as bluebird from 'bluebird';
import { Application } from 'express';
import { connect, connection, disconnect, mongo } from 'mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

import 'reflect-metadata'; // this shim is required for routing-controllers
import { createExpressServer, useContainer } from 'routing-controllers';
import { Container } from 'typedi';

import { getEnv } from './Service/Env';

// middleware
import { AuthenticateTokenMiddleware } from './Middleware/AuthenticateTokenMiddleware';
import { CorsHeadersMiddleware } from './Middleware/CorsHeadersMiddleware';
import { DisableAllExceptGetMiddleware } from './Middleware/DisableAllExceptGetMiddleware';
import { ParseTokenMiddleware } from './Middleware/ParseTokenMiddleware';

// controllers
import { init } from 'ooyala-express';
import { AudioController } from './Controller/V1/AudioController';
import { MovieController } from './Controller/V1/MovieController';
import { RootController } from './Controller/V1/RootController';
import { Indexer } from './indexer';

class App {
  public express: Application;

  constructor() {
    (<any> mongoose).Promise = bluebird;
    connect(getEnv('MONGODB_URI'), { useMongoClient: true });
    useContainer(Container);

    Indexer.ensureIndexes();
    init({
      ooyala_api_host: getEnv('ooyala_api_host'),
      ooyala_cdn_host: getEnv('ooyala_cdn_host'),
      ooyala_rights_locker_host: getEnv('ooyala_rights_locker_host'),
      ooyala_player_host: getEnv('ooyala_player_host'),
      player_expiration_window: getEnv('player_expiration_window'),
    });

    this.express = createExpressServer({
      // Disable so we don't get a nasty serialized mongoose document.
      // If they fix the issue with Expose/Exclude not being respected then
      // perhaps this could be set back to true
      classTransformer: false,
      controllers: [
        RootController,
        AudioController,
        MovieController,
      ],
      middlewares: [
        // Order is important. Middlewares are executed in index order.
        CorsHeadersMiddleware,
        DisableAllExceptGetMiddleware,
        ParseTokenMiddleware,
        AuthenticateTokenMiddleware,
      ],
    });
  }

}

export default new App().express;
```